# Can't get my images to show in Rails Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

I want to test my emails in dev mode, but I can't get the images to show.

In my mailer view, I call them this way:

```
<%= image_tag("how-icon-3.png", width: "101", border: "0", style: "display: block; width: 101px;", alt: "Decorissimo - Como 1") %>
```

I've also tried with

```
<%= image_tag("/assets/how-icon-1.png", border: "0", style: "display: block; width: 101px;", alt: "Decorissimo - Como 1") %></a>
```

and with

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="dce0ec" style="background: url(<%= image_path('/mailers/user_bg.jpg') %>); background-size: cover; background-position: top center; background-repeat: no-repeat;" class="main-bg">
```

None of them show, and they get printed in the HTML like this:

```
<img alt="Decorissimo - Como 1" border="0" src="//localhost:3000/assets/how-icon-1.png" style="display: block; width: 101px;">
```

I have configured in development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'localhost:3000'
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag that you've added `image_tag('/assets...')` combined with `localhost:3000` set as the `asset_host` would mean that all of your assets/images in the email are along the lines of:

`http://localhost:3000/assets/how-icon-3.png`

This won't ever render in an email as there is no way for your email application to render something from localhost:3000 (no access to it).

On a production server, my sense is that you'd have `asset_host` be a real URL that is resolvable across the web (i.e., `http://example.com/assets/etc`).

For development, you can use a gem like [MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me) to capture your emails locally and view the images, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Anytime! Hope that the MailCatcher gem (or a similar one) works for you!